# link to dashboard page in dropdownMenu in Shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, notifications, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating dashboard in shiny. I have login panel and different users. I would like to have in right corner dropdownMenu with links to one of my dashboard page. I found some code in internet, but here are links to websites in internet. Is it possible to click on one of notificationItem and then application take me to the indicated page from the dashboard (UI)? Maybe I should use different function, not notificationItem? Any ideas?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      dropdownMenu(
        type = "notifications", 
        icon = icon("question-circle"),
        badgeStatus = NULL,
        headerText = "See also:",

        notificationItem("shiny", icon = icon("file"),
          href = "http://shiny.rstudio.com/"),
        notificationItem("shinydashboard", icon = icon("file"),
          href = "https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/")
      )
    ), 
    dashboardSidebar(), 
    dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible on this `shinydashboard` version `0.6.1`.
However, when this issue https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/208 will be closed, you will be able to add an `observeEvent` on the `id` of an `Item`.